# programmatically determine if android app has been paid

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I was wondering if there is any way to progammatically determine if the android app has been paid for?

I am going to implement the Android LVL library code in my app. But I also want to let the users first try out the app and then buy it if they like it. So how can I determine if the app has been bought and hence fully licensed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to let users try your application out first before buying release a limited free version. (Limited by features not time)

Then also release a paid application. I would recommend 'up selling' your application from the free one. i.e. promote and encourage the upgrade from the free one by saying it has more features, better this, better that..

The LVL then only belongs in the paid version, not the free one.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the new [In-app Billing API](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) but not with the existing LVL, as LVL can only be used to verify upfront purchases from the Android Market (read paid apps.)

Effectively LVL and In-app Billing server responses are the same and can be verified in the same manner.